# .bat file which copies content from current (any) location to D:\?

Tags: batch-file

How to write .bat file which copies content from current (any) location to D:\ ?

I want to copy files from many different locations to D:\ without everytime changing copy location. I want to place this .bat file which automatically copies those files from it's location (where .bat is placed) to D:\

Comment: Please show us some of your code if you want help, this website is not a code writting service

Comment: ROBOCOPY "C:\folder" "C:\new_folder" /mir this is a code to copy from folder to new folder but i want that the 1st one to be current location (where bat file is)

Answer (score 1):

```
ROBOCOPY "%~dp0" "C:\new_folder" /mir
```

Comment: Check errorlevel immediately after command and/ot Add ECHO( to the beginning of the line and see what the line resolves to and then try to do that manually from the command line. ECHO(ROBOCOPY "%~dp0" "C:\new_folder" /mir

Comment: you know, i can't get it working, but this is correct command (robocopy "C:\Users\User\Downloads" "E:\" /mov) which works from CMD but not from .bat file... maybe your code works in cmd...

Comment: Same user? You're not trying to do this in a scheduled task are you? Are you using 'Run as administrator'? Because that would be a different user too. Post the error message... or better yet; turn echo on and post the entire result.